# Change what a link looks like with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I have a Joomla based community site and with search engine friendly URLs activated in the backend my profiles are located under mysite.com/community/profile/user/"username"

I need the htaccess file to do nothing unless a URL containing "community/profile/user" is found. If that string is found then it should change the link to mysite.com/"username" but in reality be showing the page  mysite.com/community/profile/user/"username"

I think this would be rewrite rule instead of redirect, but I barely know what I'm talking about.
Can someone please tell me what code I must place in my .htaccess file in order to change this? I believe .htacces would be the best way to do what I need, but if you have another idea I'm glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

First be sure you understand .htaccess's role.

It is only read when an incomming request is made. So it will not change URLs generated by joomla.

You can however allow urls like mysite.com/eddie to actually pull content from mysite.com/blah/blah/eddie

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html

If you are looking to "train" your users, you can add a step before that to redirect the URL as well.  This get's very tricky though as if you're not careful you can get caught in a loop.

1. user clicks mysite.com/blah/blah/eddie
2. apache redirects to mysite.com/eddie
3. (browsers makes second request, user sees URL change)
4. apache sees mysite.com/eddie and loads the underlying mysite.com/blah/blah/eddie

An easier solution might be to tweak the joomla community code to generate the short urls (mysite/eddie)  and use apache to make a call direct to the plugin  (mysite/components/communit/index.php?user=eddie

Comment: I guess the best option on thepage you linked me to would be this one.

Comment: RewriteEngine on

# first try to find it in dir1/...
# ...and if found stop and be happy:
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/component/comprofiler/userprofile/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) oveemo.com/$1 [L]

# else go on for other Alias or ScriptAlias directives,
# etc.
RewriteRule ^ - [PT]

Comment: Thanks for your response I tried this, but I get a 404 error for every page except the home URL mysite.com          Can you see what mistake I have made in the code?